# Show multiple awardable badges in the list of available badges even if the badge has been awarded

Tags: feature-request, badges

Recently I’ve suddenly got a second [Socratic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) badge. This badge can be awarded multiple times, but currently if the user already have one the badge is not shown in the list of available:

> [image: available]

My request is to add badges which can be awarded multiple times and can be tracked to the list of available badges with an ability to track them.